# White text on white background in smartgit

Tags: gui, git

I updgraded to smartgit 6.5.1 by downloading the zip file.

Now the repositories list is unreadeable white text on white ground.

How can I change the text color?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the unpacked version of smartgit and installed the deb package instead.

This fixed the problem and all looks fine.

I just had to reinsert my licence file.